# Incorrect KiCAD simulation

Tags: spice, kicad

I am learning to simulate a voltage divider using SPICE in KiCAD. Here is the circuit I created for the simulation

[image: Circuit showing voltage divider]

The simulation plot indicates that the voltage on the net connected to R1 is lower than 1 V which is the ideal DC voltage source. Are the wires not idea?

[image: Simulation waveform]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The simulation plot indicates that the voltage on the net connected to
> R1 is lower than 1 V*

Try attaching a 0 volt node reference point to the negative node of the source. It looks like both graphs could be correct if 0.25 volts were added to them but, as required when making real measurements, you need a **defined** reference node (call it the black wire of your multi-meter).

Also note that you should simulate for maybe 1 ms to get a fuller picture of what is happening (just in case).